# Rails viewcomponents test render? in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, view-components

Rails [Viewcomponents](https://viewcomponent.org/) allow you to test if a component has rendered in minitest using
`refute_component_rendered` but how do you do the same in RSpec?

```
class SometimesNotRenderedComponent < ViewComponent::Base
  def initialize(my_param)
    @my_param = my_param
  end

  def render?
    # test this
  end
end


it "renders nothing when..." do
  render_inline(described_class.new(my_param))

  # expect(page).to  ... have no content
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's dig a little, otherwise, the answer would be quite short.

The code for `refute_component_rendered` is pretty simple:
*https://github.com/ViewComponent/view_component/blob/v2.78.0/lib/view_component/test_helpers.rb#L14*

```rb
def refute_component_rendered
  assert_no_selector("body")
end
```

*assert_no_selector* is a *Capybara* matcher. Negative matchers for *rspec* are defined [dynamically](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/3.37.1/lib/capybara/rspec/matchers.rb#L165-L166) with a prefix `have_no_` and are not documented.

`have_selector` delegates to *assert_selector*.
*https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/RSpecMatchers#have_selector-instance_method*

Which means `have_no_selector` [delegates](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/3.37.1/lib/capybara/rspec/matchers/have_selector.rb#L21) to *assert_no_selector*.

You can use either one, it's just a matter of [preference](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop-rspec/cops_rspec_capybara.html#rspeccapybaranegationmatcher):

```rb
it "does not render" do
  render_inline(described_class.new(nil))
  expect(page).to have_no_selector("body")
  expect(page).not_to have_selector("body")
end

it "renders, but why" do
  # why match on `body`? it is just how `render_inline` method works,
  #   https://github.com/ViewComponent/view_component/blob/v2.78.0/lib/view_component/test_helpers.rb#L56
  # it assignes whatever the result of `render` to @rendered_content, like this:
  @rendered_content = "i'm rendering"

  # when you call `page`
  #   https://github.com/ViewComponent/view_component/blob/v2.78.0/lib/view_component/test_helpers.rb#L10
  # it wraps @rendered_content in `Capybara::Node::Simple`
  #   https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Node/Simple
  # if content is empty, there is no body
  #   Capybara::Node::Simple.new("").native.to_html
  #   # => "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n\n"

  puts page.native.to_xhtml # to see what you're matching on

  expect(page).to_not have_no_selector("body")
end
```

I've double checked:

```html
$ bin/rspec spec/components/badge_component_spec.rb

BadgeComponent
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
  does not render
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <body>
    <p>i'm rendering</p>
  </body>
</html>
  renders, but why

Finished in 0.06006 seconds (files took 2.11 seconds to load)
2 examples, 0 failures
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to show your workings and not just the answer (which would still have been useful!). Everything working thanks!